# Trouble with login when gmail ALLAUTH and user's email coincide

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-login

models.py

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None # remove username field
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email Address"), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Full Name",max_length=100)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Phone Number", blank=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # fields required when creating a new user in terminal

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

urls.py

```
# gmail OAUTH
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

settings.py

```
# Allauth Settings

SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET=True
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```

For your context, my app uses email instead of username to log the user in, and for OAUTH, I use gmail. At the moment, if I log in through gmail using an email that DID NOT REGISTER directly to the app, I will be able to log in like usual and redirected to the home page. But if I try to log in through gmail with an email that DID REGISTER to my app beforehand, I will be instead redirected to this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/social/signup/
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone help me with this? The desired result should be that for the latter scenario, the user should be redirected to the home page of the app just like the former scenario.